# how to create combobox onchange with programmatically

Tags: c#, combobox

basically, i create a combobox from toolbox and drag it into Form. but this time, i create a combobox with programmatically like this..

```
ComboBox filterKeyComboBox      = new ComboBox() { Left = 100, Top = 22, Width = 150, DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList, DataSource = null };
```

then i fill it with this..

```
filterKeyComboBox.Items.Clear();
bs.DataSource = fieldTable;
filterKeyComboBox.DataSource = bs;
filterKeyComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

then i want to create eventhandler where every i change selected item  from that combobox...

i tried like this..

```
filterAktifComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) =>
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Test onchange selected item");
 };
```

i dont know why, thats "Test onchange selected item" not printed in log.

how to create event item change in combobox with programmatically?

Comment: Looking at your code, I would have expected it to work although obviously you've given the combo box a different name in the index changed ... so.. its a bit hard to tell .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is "filterAktifComboBox" that you are giving the event?
Shouldn't you be doing it like this:

```
filterKeyComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
     Console.WriteLine("Test onchange selected item");
};
```

Wich sets the event to

```
filterKeyComboBox
```